# Android. Как JSONArray конвертировать double[]?

Tags: java, android, json

Как из массив JSONArry сделать массив double[]? 
Без добавления сторонних библиотек.

```
try{
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[\"9.35\",\"123\",\"51.242\"]");
} catch (JSONException e){}
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы собираетесь каким-то образом преобразовать строки в числа?

Comment: Ой, сейчас исправлю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[\"9.35\",\"123\",\"51.242\"]");

double[] numbers = new double[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    numbers[i] = jsonArray.optDouble(i);
}
```